# How to access a variable defined in secret.yml and required in other Ruby script

Tags: ruby, variables, scope, require

The secrets.yml file contains:

```
should_preferred_browser_driver: 0
```

In another script of the project called "rails_helper.rb", I want to access that variable.

```rb
  if should_preferred_browser_driver
    return Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
  else
    return Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
  end
```

It displays an error:

```
Can not find 'should_preferred_browser_driver'
```

What is the way to access the variable which is defined in secrets.yml in rails_helper.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Rails, you should be able to access `should_preferred_browser_driver` variable by:

```rb
Rails.application.secrets.should_preferred_browser_driver
```

However, maybe a better approach is to handle with config within your ENV variables instead of the secrets. [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gems are common in many projects.

```
# config/application.yml -- Figaro example
  SHOULD_PREFERRED_BROWSER_DRIVER: 0
```

```rb
# specs/rails_helper.rb
  if Integer(ENV.fetch("SHOULD_PREFERRED_BROWSER_DRIVER") { 0 }) 
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails.application.secrets.should_preferred_browser_driver

Thanks Conor, it is working now with above solution